# Obtaining the total from a percentage

Tags: arithmetic

$x$ is $20$ percent of $t$.

```
t=?; //to compute
x=198;
```

**Example**

```
compressed = 64;
uncompressed = (100 / 20) * 64;
```

//is it correct?

How can I compute $t$?

Comment: @Harold,  Sometimes a problem has multiple solutions.

Comment: @Harold , All of them are not know all the things. It's simple and trivial , I know. It's depend on the scenario.

Comment: I have deleted Harold's completely inappropriate comment. @Harold: Any further such incident will be cause for a suspension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**x is 20% of t** means: $x=0.2\cdot t \quad \implies  \quad t=5\cdot x$